# How can I use the compiler to infer the type of a static member?

Tags: f#

How can I use the compiler to infer the type of a static member?

In C# 6.0, the compiler can infer the type of a static property or method by providing the `"using static <namespace>.<class>"` directive.

Thus, I want to write as little code as possible.

**I have the following static members:**

```
module Mock

type Profile() =

    static member SomeUserName = "some_user_name"
    static member SomePassword = "some_password"
```

**I then define some types and a function:**

```
open Mock

(*Types*)
type User =        User of string
type Password =    Password of string
type Credentials = { User:User; Password:Password }

(*Functions*)
let login credentials =
    false
```

**I then have the following test:**

```
[<Test>]
let ``sign in`` () =

    // Setup
    let credentials = { User=     User     Profile.SomeUserName
                        Password= Password Profile.SomePassword } 
    // Test
    credentials |> login 
                |> should equal true
```

I would like to remove the Profile type qualifier from SomeUserName and SomePassword and do this instead:

```
// Setup
let credentials = { User=     User     SomeUserName
                    Password= Password SomePassword }
```

Do I have to explicitly specify a type of a static member?

Comment: Make `Profile` a module, not a static type. Also, you're misusing the term "infer type".

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. How should I phrase it?

Comment: "To infer type" means "to know what the type of something should be based on its context and/or usage". This does not apply to your problem: the compiler is perfectly able to infer that the type of your properties is `string` based on the value you return from them. What you actually want, I would phrase as "bring these properties into scope". Also, from your questions, I'd say that you lack a systematic approach. You seem to be trying to poke around in the dark without taking the time to know what's what and how it's supposed to work.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I'll continue to ask questions even if they do appear silly. By the way, you're not obligated to answer them. However, I do appreciate all the guidance I've received on here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The obvious solution, as Fyodor Soikin points out, is to simply make `Profile` a module.

```
module Profile =
    let someUserName = "some_user_name"
    let somePassword = "some_password"
```

Then you can just:

```
open Profile

let credentials = { 
    User = User someUserName;
    Password = Password somePassword 
    }
```

Incidentally, while it may not be possible to open static classes in F# at the moment, this looks set to change in future versions - this feature has been "approved in principle".  See the [user voice item](https://fslang.uservoice.com/forums/245727-f-language/suggestions/6958404-allow-opening-of-static-classes-matching-the-c-d) for more.